# Woocommerce product Loop Query

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to print current woocommerce loop query on content-product.php file

i tried $wpdb->last_query; but it gives individual query for each product

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://zeropointdevelopment.com/woocommerce-products-loop-wpquickies/

Comment: Shows individual since this is used in archive-product template where loops products and loads for each product content-product template. Current loop is in archive-product template not content-product .